# What is the real value of WordArray when it is used as an AES key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

let key = "nfu-eca-EBLrKCb3AUu*X%3+lh7=o2jUmhp1(z&6";
let username = "01032219";

let result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(username, CryptoJS.MD5(key), {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});

console.log(result.toString()); 
// output: 1oIadjvmeIeH/UGd5QPCvg==
```

As you can see, I use CryptoJS to encrypt the username. **I'm confused about `CryptoJS.MD5(key)`.** It is a WordArray object, what is its real value when it is passed to the `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()` function as an AES encryption key?

I tried to reproduce the encryption process of the above code at the [AES online encryption site](https://the-x.cn/en-us/cryptography/Aes.aspx).

- plain text to be encrypted: "01032219"
- cipher mode: ECB
- padding: PKCS7

I fill in the MD5(include 16/32-bit lowercase/uppercase) of the same key string(*"nfu-eca-EBLrKCb3AUu*X%3+lh7=o2jUmhp1(z&6"*) as Secret Key.
But the final result is not the same as the output of the code.

[image]

Comment: _"Because I'm new to stackoverflow, I can't show you the image directly..."_ - That's not relevant because: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)"_

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] -> Add the expected output (as text in the question itself)

Comment: You have to take the hash you call 32 bit MD5 (strange name by the way, 128 bit or 16 byte or 32 hexadecimal digits would be more appropriate), upper or lower case doesn't matter, and enter this in the online tool via the *HEX values [Editable]* input field. Then you get the value of the CryptoJS code.

Comment: And the MD5 value you specified as 32 bit lowercase can simply be determined in CryptoJS with `CryptoJS.MD5(key).toString()`.

Comment: A great help! I get it. Thanks a million. @Topaco